# Use of undeclared type 'GraphQLMappable' Apollo-iOS

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode8, graphql, apollo

I am trying to build [this Apollo example app](https://github.com/apollographql/frontpage-ios-app/blob/bd135495294708b54c13ca91dfc2761db352be71/FrontPage/schema.json) and am finding that the graphQL types referenced, such as GraphQLMappable, GraphQLResultReader, and GraphQLNamedFragment are throwing respective errors:

Use of undeclared type 'GraphQLMappable'

I have linked Apollo framework to my Xcode project [image: here is a graphic example of the error and linked apollo framework]

here is a graphic example of the error and linked apollo framework

What is the proper step to debug this issue and properly configure graphql Apollo for xCode? Thanks in advance.

Comment: how did it work?? Please help

Answer (score 0):

I figure out it by updating submodule to latest version.

1. cd Carthage/Checkouts/apollo-ios
2. git checkout master

   warning: unable to rmdir 'docs/themes/meteor': Directory not empty
   Previous HEAD position was 6ced4b7... 0.8.0
   Switched to branch 'master'
   Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.